# What is the difference between 64-bit PCI slot and PCI-X slot?

Tags: pci

I need to identify what kind of slots are available from my computer based on the shape of the slot. So far, I can easily tell the difference between 32-bit PCI and PCIe slots but I am having problem with 64-bit PCI and PCI-X slots.

From my googling, the slot itself looks like either a 3.3V 64-bit slot or a 3.3V PCI-X slot, but I cannot find any article that put both kind of slots together side-by-side for comparison. Is there any way to identify the slot based on the physical shape of the slot only?

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT91p.png) :

> The 64-bit PCI connector can be distinguished from 32-bit by being longer, and from PCI-X by having three segments, with the one in the middle much shorter than the others. PCI-X slots can be distinguished from 64-bit PCI as the small segment is first, instead of in the center.

[image: Comparison of slots]

Comment: 3.3V 64-bit PCI slot has the small segment first as well.

Comment: Universal 64-bit PCI == PCI-X, then?

Comment: @Hery: there shouldn't be any significant physical differences between the slots. The newer PCI cards - 3.3V will fit (and work) in a PCI-X slot, and PCI-X cards will fit in an older PCI slot (as long as the voltage - 3.3V - matches). The standards are backwards compatible with the slowest connected card determining the bus speed. Perhaps you will have better success looking at the chipset or model of the motherboard.

Comment: so physically there is no difference at all... For completeness' sake, what about 5V 64-bit PCI and 5V 64-bit PCI-X slot? Are they the same physically as well?

Comment: @cyberx86, maybe this new question adds a curious detail about what could happen in extreme PCI voltage compatibility cases? http://superuser.com/questions/839893/i-have-a-3-3volt-pci-ethernet-card-working-on-a-5volt-pci-slot-how-is-it-possib

Comment: @KyleSmith No. The slots appear similar but PCI-X is different electrically. They are supposedly compatible with each other but in practice there were issues - a PCI-X card (which in PCI-X mode will run at 66 MHz, 64 bits) would often drop to 33 MHz, 32 bit, in anything but a PCI-X slot.